# What are some proofs that the list $1,z,...,z^m$ is linearly independent in $P(\mathbb{F})$ for each nonnegative integer $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

In Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* we are asked to verify the assertion that the list $1,z,...,z^m$ is linearly independent (l.i) in $P(\pmb{\mathbb{F}})$ for each nonnegative integer $m$.

The way I showed this was to assume these vectors of $P(\pmb{\mathbb{F}})$ are linearly dependent (l.d.). That is, there is some linear combination of these vectors, with coefficients not all zero, that is the zero polynomial.

Let such a polynomial be

$$p(z)=\lambda_0+\lambda_1z+...+\lambda_mz^m=0$$

which is true for $\lambda_i$ not all zero and for all $z$.

Then, $z=0$ implies $p(0)=\lambda_0=0$.

Since polynomials are differentiable everywhere, we can compute the derivative at $z=0$

$$p'(0)=\lambda_1=0$$

and we can keep doing this to find that all the $\lambda$'s are zero.

This result contradicts our assumption that these coefficients were not all zero.

Hence, we can infer that in fact our initial vectors $1,z,...,z^m$ are l.i.

**Questions**

1. Is this proof correct?
2. What are some alternative ways of proving the result in question?

Comment: Two comments: is $P(\mathbb{F}) = \mathbb{F} [x]$? And your proof idea is good, but derivation will cause some problems in positive characteristic. You could try to use the fact that $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a domain. You could also show that every family of polynomials graded in degree is free

Comment: I am not sure what your notation $\mathbb{F}[x]$ means. In the notation I am using (from the book), $P(\mathbb{F})$ is the vector space of all polynomials with coeffiecients in field $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Ok then you should prefer the notation $\mathbb{F}[x]$, usually $P$ is used for projective spaces. Points of my commentary are correct though. If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, you don't necessarily have $n x \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$ (take $\mathbb{F}_2$ for example).

Comment: How do you define a polynomial? The proof depends on this a lot. For some definitions it's downright trivial, for others it's harder.

Comment: It should be stated that Axler's book only contemplates fields with characteristic zero

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ is defined in this book as a function $p:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}$ such that there exist $a_0,...,a_m\in\mathbb{F}$ satisfying $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_mz^m$ for all $z\in\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Then the assertion in your post is not true. Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field. Then $\prod_{x\in\mathbb F}(z-x)$ is identical to the zero function. For instance, in $\mathbb F_2$ we have $z^2-z=z(z-1)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb F_2$, making $z^2$ and $z$ linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

So what you have written as $P (F)$ is commonly written $F[z]$ the free $F$ algebra with $z$ for generator. It is more commonly called the ring of univariate polynomials. You proof idea is good since you want to use induction, but the derivation is not sufficient; usual fields like $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ have zero as a characteristic, which means the morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to F$ that sends $1$ to $1_F$ is injective. For some fields like finite fields this is not the case, we say that the characteristic is positive.

An example would be $\mathbb{F}_2$, the field of integers modulo $2$, if you multiply anything by $2$ it's the same as multiplying by $0$ since $2 = 0$ in this field. Then if you derivate $z^2$, you get $2z = 0$, but you don't have $x^2 = k \in \mathbb{F}_2$...

Now lets correct this proof; our induction property is the following: For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the family $1, \dots, z^n$ if free.

for $n=0$ it's clear

now if it has been verified for $n-1$, take
$$\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 z + \cdots + \lambda_n z^n$$
By evaluating in $0$ you get $\lambda_0 = 0$ this gives you
$$z(\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n z^{n-1} ) = 0$$
Since $F[z]$ s a domain and $z \neq 0$, we have $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n z^{n-1} = 0$. By induction, $\lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_n = 0$

---

If you already had this result, you could have stated by uniqueness of the coefficients of a polynomial, $\lambda_0 = \cdots = \lambda_n = 0$. But the method here works for any family graded in degree.

Comment: What is a "free family"? The level of this particular book is that of a second course in Linear Algebra by a non-mathematician major. This problem came up in the second chapter of the book entitled "Finite-dimensional vector spaces". I think you cited "Algebra". I haven't studied this yet. With regards to your comment on my proof, I think my limited understanding of the concepts involved precludes my understanding. I did understand your proof by induction though.

Comment: You can forget the algebra part, just stick to the ring of polynomials of variable $z$. Free family  means linearly independent :)

Comment: The first part says that your proof is valid for the field of rationals, real numbers or complex numbers